# Listing products related to store in google maps search results

Tags: channel-entries, zoo-visitor, google-maps-for-ee

```
{exp:gmap:results order_by="distance" sort="asc"}
    {if has_searched}
        {results}
            <script>console.log("{entry_id}");</script>
            {!-- Entry ID for store is output to console --}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="product"}
                <script>console.log("{entry_id}");</script>
                {!-- store entry ID is output to console, not product entry ID --}
                <tr>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
               </td>
           </tr>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/results}
{/exp:gmap:results}
```

I am trying to output a tabular list of all the products associated with the stores returned by the search results. In this setup, the product entries have a store relationship field. But not vice versa. That is because Channel Form does not allow the submission of data to two entries at a time (i.e. submit the product data to product channel, then append the product ID to the products relationship in the store channel entry).

The products are created by the stores since the store channel is really the channel containing all the member data since I use the Zoo Visitor plugin. So, the stores (i.e. members) create the products.

As I understand it, the `{results}{/results}` pair tag loops through the store channel. A solution I thought of was to have the product channel entry loop with the `author_id` parameter set to equal the `entry_id` of the store channel. But I get no output with this parameter:

```
{exp:gmap:results order_by="distance" sort="asc"}
    {if has_searched}
        {results}
            <script>console.log("{entry_id}");</script>
            {!-- Entry ID for store is output to console --}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="product" author_id="{entry_id}"}
                <script>console.log("{entry_id}");</script>
                {!-- store entry ID is output to console, not product entry ID --}
                <tr>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
               </td>
           </tr>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/results}
{/exp:gmap:results}
```

Without that parameter, I get the products, but I get every single product entry whose repetition is equal to the number of stores. So, I tested to see what entry ID I get inside the outer loop and the inner loop. In both instances I get the store entry ID.

Is there a way to resolve this so that I can **1**: filter the products with the `author_id` parameter being equal to the entry ID of the outer loop entry ID? And **2**: fix the inner loop so that `{entry_id}` returns the product ID, not the store ID?

Answer (score 0):

I would use VMG nested.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vmg-nested

This plugin allows you to use your channel tags in the exact same way, but allow you to **prefix** your variable outputs. Example:

```
{exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries channel="news" prefix="news}
    <!-- outside entry_id -->
    {news:entry_id}

    {exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries channel="blog" prefix="blog" author_id="{news:entry_id}"

            <!-- inside entry_id -->
            {blog:entry_id}

            <!-- ... magic! outside entry_id -->
            {news:entry_id}

    {/exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries}

{/exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries}
```

This might be your ticket.